# What component failure could cause this?

Tags: vauxhall, thermostat, corsa

[image: Instrument display indicating -40°C]

Despite the temperature here being +13°C today, this 2007 Vauxhall Corsa has started reporting anywhere from -37 to -40. My gut feel is that there must be an external thermostat that has failed, however I cannot think of a failure mode that would give this variable output.

Is there a reference component which could fail, or if not, what do I need to check in the thermostat?

Comment: A broken sensor wire or poor terminal connection is a possible cause.

Comment: There's an external sensor behind the front bumper. Very cheap to replace, but also check the wiring in case something got broken.

Comment: That's an answer @PeteCon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electric thermometers are called thermocouples, the way they work is that they offer less resistance to electrical current as temperature goes up, i.e. as it gets hotter the voltage on the circuit goes up. Themrocouples are calibrated to give specific voltages at specific temperatures, the temperature readout is simply an indication of the voltage on the circuit.

-40 looks like the lowest possible reading, so if you know it isn't right that indicates there is no voltage on the circuit, so most likely the sensor has failed or the wiring for the sensor has failed. I don't know vauxhalls, but a quick search shows that loads of people replace the sensor (in the front bumper) and they still have problems, so it would be worth your while to check the wiring for the sensor before spending hard-earned wonga on it.